# How to override package.json `type` with typescript compiler options?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

TypeScript's `--module node16 --moduleResolution node16` options

1. enables [node import](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports), [subpath export](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/packages.html#subpath-exports), and [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/packages.html#conditional-exports)
2. Enforces node's [mandatory file extensions](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions)
3. emits esm *or* cjs depending on package.json `type: module` or `.mjs` file extensions

This is perfect when a module emits either commonjs or ecmascript modules but I can't figure out how to dual publish.

Conditional exports allow us to define different entry points for `require` and `import`

```
"exports": {
  "import": "./dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js"
},
```

But in order to emit esm to dist/esm and cjs to dist/cjs I need to change the file extensions, or the package.json types between builds, because of point 3 above.

Is there a typescript compiler option to override package.json type or the file extension and emit a specific format while using `node16` module? `esnext` or `es2022` options don't work because they will not enable points 1 or 2.

Comment: I'm not positive that I understand the question, but if you're asking about how to get `.mjs` vs `.js` vs `.cjs` extensions for the compiled JS output files, the compiler automatically maps `.ts` to `.js`, `.mts` to `.mjs`, and `.cts` to `.cjs`. See documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#new-file-extensions). If that answers your question, I can write it up as one. If not — what am I missing/misunderstanding?

Comment: @jsejcksn IIUC, OP needs to output both

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a typescript compiler option to override package.json type or the file extension and emit a specific format while using node16 module?

No. Not yet anyway.

The TypeScript team [keep](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/54546) [talking](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54593) about dual build support, but are too busy debating on the implementation. They don't really seem to be a fan of dual packages and they continue to [refuse to rewrite specifiers](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577). However, there is [one team member who is trying to change their opinion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54593#issuecomment-1585207324) on that. They seem to want to require two package.json files, which feels very much  like an anti-pattern, especially since Node.js supports the [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) field.

As you noted, the best you can do is create two package.json files so the `type` can be inferred while building to `--module node16` (or `nodenext`). For an example on how to run dual builds, the package [@knighted/duel](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel) supports dual builds with `tsc` using **only one** package.json and tsconfig.json by dynamically creating a second package.json with the dual `type`.  [Specifiers](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers) are also rewritten with [@knighted/specifier](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/specifier). The [notes](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel#notes) provide some more details on TypeScript's current support of dual builds.